# how to write every element of an array in a line of a textbox C#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, multiline

hi I need to write each element of an array in a line of a textbox
I have tried this code my array is taken from an input file also the number of element of the array

```
string[] myArray = values[(int)TextBoxIndices.idcourses].Split('-');
string[] tempArray = new string[Int32.Parse(values[(int)TextBoxIndices.totalnbre])];
tempArray = idc.Lines;

for (int t = 0; t < Int32.Parse(values[(int)TextBoxIndices.totalnbre]); t++)
{ 
   tempArray = myArray[t] + '\n'; 
}
```

Comment: And what didn't work with that?

Comment: when I run the program an error comes in the for loop(index was outside the bounds)...@BradleyDotNET

Comment: @EdgardAbouKheir Where, specifically?

Comment: the code of @JeremyK worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is using a value taken from your values array as the count limit, but you are indexing myArray. As you stated in your comment, you are going outside your array bounds.

You should have:

```
for (int t = 0; t < myArray.Length; t++)
```